# Creating Folders in another Server/Machine Using Silverlight/WCF

Tags: wcf, silverlight-4.0

I need to create some set of folders in a client machine or in some network machine. The idea is user will upload some files to the server instaed of storing that files in our server we plan to save that files in the client sepefied machine. That machine will also been in the network only and also in the same domain. Can any one guide me how to create a folder and also upload the files to that  network machine??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

For silverlight you can use Isolated storage as you don't have access to the users complete hard drive, you can use it like such

```
var myStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
myStore.CreateDirectory("theFolder")
```

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't want to store in Isolated Storage. The Idea is Once the User uploads the document instead on storing the doc in our server we need to save the doc in some other server.